# Problem with Tensorflow GPU-anyone knows how to solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Problem and I don't know what to do, has anyone expirienced this problem or knows what to do? I want to use my GPU, but it is using my CPU. I have a RTX 2060 CUDA 11.4 and the cudNN version for it. Everything is set up and installed.
heres my "error" message:

```
2021-07-03 18:04:08.192447: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.322737: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.364105: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.2GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 245.91GiB/s
2021-07-03 18:04:14.364218: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.378476: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.378575: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.386958: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.389748: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.395241: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.400934: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.401962: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-07-03 18:04:14.402129: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-07-03 18:04:14.402506: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-07-03 18:04:14.404017: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.2GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 245.91GiB/s
2021-07-03 18:04:14.405038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-07-03 18:04:14.999077: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-07-03 18:04:14.999188: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
2021-07-03 18:04:14.999495: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
2021-07-03 18:04:14.999834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3961 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
W0703 18:04:15.003447 19488 mirrored_strategy.py:379] Collective ops is not configured at program startup. Some performance features may not be enabled.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I0703 18:04:15.198488 19488 mirrored_strategy.py:369] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: 2000
I0703 18:04:15.203375 19488 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: 2000
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0703 18:04:15.203375 19488 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:557: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0703 18:04:15.220866 19488 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:557: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
I0703 18:04:15.227620 19488 dataset_builder.py:163] Reading unweighted datasets: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
I0703 18:04:15.228616 19488 dataset_builder.py:80] Reading record datasets for input file: ['Tensorflow\\workspace\\annotations\\train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I0703 18:04:15.228616 19488 dataset_builder.py:81] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0703 18:04:15.230612 19488 dataset_builder.py:87] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:101: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
W0703 18:04:15.240116 19488 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:101: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:236: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0703 18:04:15.278014 19488 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:236: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0703 18:04:20.026224 19488 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W0703 18:04:22.222466 19488 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py:464: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0703 18:04:23.631255 19488 deprecation.py:330] From C:\Users\vrabe\Dropbox\Programming\Python Thilo\Artificial Intelligence\Object Detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py:464: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
2021-07-03 18:04:25.670524: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

Comment: There is no error message in your log, and what is your evidence that the CPU is being used instead of GPU?

Comment: It looks like you are running on GPU: `2021-07-03 18:04:14.405038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0` what makes you think there is an issue?

Comment: They are just the information message as they are prefixed with `I`, if it is the error message they would be prefixed with `E` or `W` for warnings. Here you are using `GPU`. You can check with `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`, which returns the name of a GPU device if available or a empty string. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[List](https://www.jquery-az.com/3-ways-convert-python-list-string-join-map-str/) physical devices ( and print number of physical devices ) using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/list_physical_devices

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("List of GPUs " * ','.join(map(str, physical_devices)))
print("Num GPUs:", len(physical_devices))
```

Check if a GPU is used and name it with https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/gpu_device_name

```
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

You can then work on the named device with as in this (Test) example

```
class MyTest(tf.test.TestCase):

  def test_add_on_gpu(self):
    if not tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support():
      self.skipTest("test is only applicable on GPU")

    with tf.device(tf.test.gpu_device_name()):
      self.assertEqual(tf.math.add(1.0, 2.0), 3.0)
```